# How to remove Windows Vista bootloader?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I just removed Windows Vista from my computer by simply formatting the partition (as described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows7/Uninstall-Windows-7-on-a-multiboot-system)). But - as I guessed - this does not change anything with the Bootloader. So, when I start Windows, it still asks me if I want to boot Vista or XP.

So I tried to run `bootcfg` on Windows XP to fix this problem, but it just holds the entry for Windows XP itself. Nothing about Windows Vista. So the bootloader in use is not the one from Windows XP.

Ok, I could run `fixmbr`. But I also use GRUB as primary bootloader which will be removed from MBR with this. I could fix that again by booting from a Linux Live CD and running some commands from there. But is this really the one and only way to get rid of the Windows Vista bootloader?

For those who are confused now: Yes I use GRUB *and* a Windows bootloader. When I select Windows XP in GRUB the Windows bootloader appears and asks me if I want to start XP or Vista. Don't ask me why. It happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **VistaBootPro** or **DualBootPro**. Install this software on your Windows XP system and delete the Windows Vista entry.

- Download VistaBootPro from  [here](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-126-vista-boot-pro)
- Download DualBootPro from [here](http://www.vistabootpro.org/)

Resource taken from [here](http://www.pctipsbox.com/uninstall-vista-bootloader/)

Comment: VistaBootPro worked for me.

Comment: Glad to here it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Super Grub can fix most boot problems, even with windows.

http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot/Super-Grub-Disk-8071.shtml

Comment: Super Grub Disk helped me a lot in the past. The next time I have this particular problem I'll try to solve it that way.